# 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

It's my first post on stakcoverflow because I don't find any clue to solve this message "'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'" that appear when I call trainer.fit on my train dataset to create a neural network model under Spark in Python

here is my code

```html
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier, MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel
from pyspark.mllib.feature import StandardScaler
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
   
### Import data in Spark ###
RDD_RAWfileWH= sc.textFile("c:/Anaconda2/Cognet/Data_For_Cognet_ready.csv")
header = RDD_RAWfileWH.first()
# Delete header from RAWData
RDD_RAWfile1 = RDD_RAWfileWH.filter(lambda x: x != header)
# Split each line of the RDD
RDD_RAWfile = RDD_RAWfile1.map(lambda line:[float(x) for x in line.split(',')])

FinalData = RDD_RAWfile.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0],[row[1:]]))

(trainingData, testData) = FinalData.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

layers = [15, 2, 3]

# create the trainer and set its parameters
trainer = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(maxIter=100, layers=layers, blockSize=128,seed=1234)
# train the model
model = trainer.fit(trainingData)
```

and the trace

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-123dce2b085a> in <module>()
     46 trainer = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(maxIter=100, layers=layers, blockSize=128,seed=1234)
     47 # train the model
---> 48 model = trainer.fit(trainingData)
     49     # compute accuracy on the test set
     50  #   result = model.transform(test)

C:\Users\piod7321\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\ml\pipeline.pyc in fit(self, dataset, params)
     67                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     68             else:
---> 69                 return self._fit(dataset)
     70         else:
     71             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

C:\Users\piod7321\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.pyc in _fit(self, dataset)
    131 
    132     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 133         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    134         return self._create_model(java_model)
    135 

C:\Users\piod7321\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.pyc in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    128         """
    129         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 130         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    131 
    132     def _fit(self, dataset):

AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

I'am not an expert on Spark so If anyone know what is this jdf attribute and how to solve this issue it will be very helpfull for me.

thanks a lot

Comment: You're trying to use `ml` algorithm with RDD. You'll a `DataFrame` here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, But, I don't understand very well,because my trainingData is an RDD.

Comment: `{"pyspark.mllib": "pyspark.rdd.RDD", "pyspark.ml": "pyspark.sql.DataFrame"}`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot zero323, I understand now, MultilayerPerceptronClassifier is available with pyspark.ml and it works with DataFrame only while pyspark.mllib works with RDD and MultilayerPerceptronClassifier is not available under mlLib (and it will never be),  now  I have to change the way I load the data in Spark ans load it as a dataframe